# How does Unity's dash index and search work?

Tags: unity-dash

What kind of items and which attributes are indexed? E. g. desktop/launchers, documents; what metadata?

Where's the index stored? sqlite, couchdb, ...?

Which query language is used; what's the query like? How are results ranked/ordered? I'd like to see an example query.

Answer (score 11):

Unity makes use of Zeitgeist in its dash where it provides the user with easy access to its most and recently used data (files/folders/applications) as well as searching over the Zeitgeist FTS (Full Text Search) extension.

There is more development going on to bring the same features to a contacts dash where the user can browse his contacts by most/recently used.
[image]

From the [Zeitgeist website](http://zeitgeist-project.com/experience/):

> This page also explains the activity journal (you need to install this yourself) where you can find the answer to how results ranked/ordered and more.

So it uses metadata.

The 2nd part of your question is answered from another page from that site: 
Which technologies does Zeitgeist use?

1. Python
2. DBus
3. SQLite.

Comment: The core part of Zeitgeist uses these. Plus `glib` for mainloop. For fts extension (which is also installed by default) it needs `xapian`

Comment: the link seems to be broken but here's one to the [Launchpad project](https://launchpad.net/zeitgeist-project)