# Sorting Unity 3D Search Results

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

When I hit the "Windows Key" and search for an application, the order is always incorrect (imo).

As a very simple example, I'll search for "calc".

[image: Searching for Calc]

The default Ubuntu calculator is 3rd from the left (next to the Calc widget and Libre Office Calc).  I noticed this the first time and assumed the order would adjust upon usage.  Not so.  I NEVER use the Calc widget and only rarely use Libre Office Calc, but I use gcalctool (Ubuntu's "calculator") almost every day.  But it still comes up 3rd every time.

Is there any way to sort these results according to usage?

Comment: sorting is still unclear to me, too. http://askubuntu.com/questions/37814/how-does-unitys-dash-index-and-search-work

Comment: While looking around, I saw the Zeitgeist mentioned here and there, but as far as I can tell the actual usage isn't being used to sort the search results - which seems a bit silly to me, being that the purpose of this search tool is for quick access, but unsorted results has the opposite effect.

Comment: I would suggest you use something like "synapse". It is _much_ faster and does what you want. I don't use the unity search because it opens slow and the sorting is weird as you mentioned.

Comment: Looks like it is a known bug in Unity. https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/752773

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my search thus far, I've found no answer, except the [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/752773) [JohanSJA](https://askubuntu.com/users/21846/johansja) offered in his comment on the OP, which claims it as a feature.

Unsorted search results are completely useless.  Imagine if google didn't sort your results, or stackoverflow, or any software with a search function.  There would be no use in searching.  Search without relevancy sorting is an incomplete feature.

I'm marking this as my answer, but only because there are currently no answers to the problem.  I will change it should a better answer arise.

Answer (score 0):

The search isn't meant to be sorted in that manner, AFAIK, it simply returns results based on their name.

Also, if you are using a newer version of Zeitgiest (for example 0.8 from the PPA), Unity will be missing a few features.

Comment: I realize it's not working that way, but that seems to be more of a bug than an expected behavior in my mind.

Comment: @enobrev "in my mind" does not make it a bug. It is not like the issue with not being able to minimize windows from the "launcher". It is rather a matter of not using zeitgiest or using it.

Comment: Considering one definition for a software bug is an "unexpected behavior", then "in my mind" can very well define the issue as a bug.  I realize it doesn't use the Zeitegiest for sorting.  This is a failure in implementation - or rather an incomplete implementation.  I suppose that may fit very well into the gray area of what constitutes a bug, but simply stating WHY it doesn't work the way it should doesn't resolve the fact that it should work that way.  Neither does comparing it to other issues (even if they Are more serious issues).