# Best UI that still makes good use of Super button

Tags: lubuntu

This might be a weird question, but I'm looking for the best UI that still makes use of something similar to Unity's search function.

Here's the deal; I installed Lubuntu on a computer at work. It runs super fast, and I really like the layout and usability. What I don't like is that I can't find any programs that I normally use!

For example, today I was trying to find the volume control because someone had put it on mute. I couldn't find it in the menu, so I had to right click and add the little widget to the bottom right corner of my screen to unmute it.

So, I'm asking for a UI that will still allow me to search for programs and files in the same way that Unity does...but without using Unity.

Comment: No harm in asking ;) but I suspect that any thing remotely resembling "Unity's search function" will have a price in terms of performance, at least on machines with less than ideal specs. You can look at this old QnA to get an idea of what goes on behind the scenes: [How does Unity's dash index and search work?](http://askubuntu.com/q/37814/25656). There's no doubt that, with the push to mobile, the search will get less resource-hungry.

Comment: Try [Gnome-Do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Do).

Comment: Gnome-Do is pretty good. It looks pretty good, but it could be better. In the mean time, it works. Thanks!