# how to make the dash search for ODT files' contents?

Tags: libreoffice, unity-dash, search

I tested creating an ODT file and searching for a word inside the file.
As far as I can tell, the ubuntu dash cannot search inside ODT files.

But maybe I missed an option/there is some indexing and the file will appear in the dash latter.

Does the dash search inside ODT files ? Is there a way to make it do those searches ?

Comment: is there a shell program that can parse ODT files? (I think there is, but I can recall. ) i'll look into it.  what type of output are you expecting? are you trying search ODT files by key words? do you want  a list of files to come up in dash that have keywords you might type? this might get you started: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37814/how-does-unitys-dash-index-and-search-work

Comment: yes, I want a list of files to appear in the dash. These files are the files that contain the keywords