# What is the difference between locate/whereis/which

Tags: command-line, unity-dash, search, locate

What is the basic difference between `locate` `whereis` and `which` command.

The basic difference that I observed is that `locate` locates all the related file names in the entire filesystem, whereas `whereis` and `which` commands only give the location (system/local address of file) of installed application. How accurate is my observation?

How are these commands implemented internally. Why does `locate` work so fast as compared to the dash search, while `locate` has to search a particular filename matching the target string in the entire filesystem hierarchy?

Comment: and what about `type` ? :P

Comment: @jamesmstone  what do you mean by `type`, please elaborate

Comment: Sorry I was just attempting to add onto your question. [`type`](http://ss64.com/bash/type.html) is another command that seems (to my eyes) do a similar thing to the ones you mentioned.

Comment: @jamesmstone I dont think there is any type command which works in my system. I am unable to find any manual or info page for the `type` command. I tried `man type` and `info type`.

Comment: Hmm I wonder why... Are you using bash ?

Comment: @jamesmstone Yeah I am using bash terminal.

Comment: How odd, in the page I linked to above it says type is a shell builtin

Comment: @jamesmstone Well I tried to execute the commands `type type` and `type grep` they work, but I don't know why there is no documentation of `type` command

Comment: @Zanna http://askubuntu.com/questions/801289/no-man-page-or-info-page-for-type-command I have posted a question related to type command .

Comment: @Chinmaya Bash builtins like `type` don't have man pages. You can use `help type` to get info about it, or look it up in [`man bash` under "Shell builtin commands"](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/bash.1.html#shell%20builtin%20commands).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`which` finds the binary executable of the program (if it is in your PATH). `man which` explains more clearly:

> which returns the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be
>   executed in the current environment, had its arguments been given as  commands in a strictly POSIX-conformant shell.  It does this by searching the PATH for executable files matching the names of the  arguments. It does not follow symbolic links.

`whereis` finds the binary, the source, and the man page files for a program. For example

```
$ whereis gimp
/usr/bin/gimp /usr/lib/gimp /etc/gimp /usr/share/gimp /usr/share/man/man1/gimp.1.gz
```

You can get extra detail by passing the output of these commands as arguments to `ls -l` or `file`

```
$ ls -l $(which gimp)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Jun 30 19:59 /usr/bin/gimp -> gimp-2.8

$ file $(which gimp)
/usr/bin/gimp: symbolic link to gimp-2.8
```

`locate` indeed finds all the files that have the pattern specified anywhere in their paths. You can tell it to only find files and directories whose *names* (rather than full paths) include the pattern with the `-b` option, which is usually what you want, and gives a less unwieldy list.

`locate` is fast because it uses a binary database that gets periodically updated (once daily, by `cron`). You can update it yourself to ensure recently added files are found by running `sudo updatedb`

One more thing about `locate` - it doesn't care whether files still exist or not, so to avoid finding recently deleted files, use `-e`. Often I also pipe to `less` as the list can be long. Typically I do:

```
sudo updatedb && locate -b -e gimp | less
```

How Unity's dash works is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37814/how-does-unitys-dash-index-and-search-work) - it uses [Zeitgeist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitgeist_(free_software)) to index system files and learn from usage patterns, and enables other applications to make use of this data, so it is doing a lot more work than `locate`.

Comment: can you compare dash and locate command performance and implementation details? The updation of the binary database should be done after creation of any new file in system isn't it so that period would be indefinite correct or is it managed by system processes?

Comment: @Creator updating the database automatically is done by cron, once per day. You can check when you install something you can't immediately find the files with `locate`. The dash uses a completely different index - slower because it does more stuff (I edited my answer)

Comment: So to sum up locate is useful and more powerful than which or whereis but is dumb while dash is more powerful and implements machine learning. and thanks for the `sudo updatedb` your command is very helpful didnt know that although I used -e regularly.

Comment: @Creator yep you phrased it better :) happy that it helped

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
$ which samba
```

which command searches the list of programs listed down through the PATH settings

```
$ whereis samba
```

whereis command also searches for programs that are not present in the PATH setting

```
$locate samba
```

Also finds files by filename but does not search the directory structure itself but only a database prepared by updatedb. Because of that locate is faster than find but less accurate. Examples:

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest find to print all results

```
find . -type d -name gimp -print
```

and if you decide to also remove use

```
find . -type d -name gimp -print -delete
```

I hope it helps, anyone else looking for it