# Unity dash - is there a command line (CLI) interface to perform a search?

Tags: command-line, unity, unity-dash

Sometimes, I login remotely via ssh to my remote desktop and I would like to call a GUI application through ssh, to remotely display it on my laptop.

However, I do not know what the binary name is, since I usually call applications from the dash using generic terms.

Is there a commande line (CLI) interface where it would be possible, in a terminal, to perform a search in Unity Dash and obtain in the result list the application names and path to their executable commands?

I would like something like:

```
# dash --search "disks"
Name         Executable
Disks        /usr/bin/gnome-disks
```

Comment: Searching through all the `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications` would be a good start.

Comment: Related: [How does Unity's dash index and search work?](http://askubuntu.com/q/37814/117103)

Comment: `find <where> -name <what>` for example `find /etc -name libgtk`. I think there is also a locate program but that may need to be installed before you can use (sorry I'm not at my *nix box right now)

Comment: This question might be a better fit for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Elder Geek, I am not asking for an alternative for Dash, I am asking if a specific feature exists within it.  It is thus not related to software recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script that might be helpful:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for desktopFile in $(grep -irl "$1" /usr/share/applications/) ; do 
  grep --color=never 'Name=' "$desktopFile" 
  grep --color=never 'Exec=' "$desktopFile" 
  echo ''
done
```

Assuming you saved it as "searchapps", this is what it does:

```
$ searchapps disks
Name=Disk Image Writer
Exec=gnome-disks --restore-disk-image %U

Name=Disks
Exec=gnome-disks
```

Note that there might be other folders you'd like to search in addition to `/usr/share/applications`.  You'd have to modify the script accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A convenient alternative is to open `/usr/share/applications` with your favourite file browser (`nautilus` in standard Ubuntu, `pcmanfm` in Lubuntu, `thunar` in Xubuntu ...) and simply double-click on the icons you find there in order to start your program.

```
nautilus --no-desktop /usr/share/applications &

pcmanfm /usr/share/applications &

thunar /usr/share/applications &
```

I tested this in a terminal window with remote access via

```
ssh -X user@IP-adress
```

and it works for me.